# How to Make a Javascript Image Enlarge on Rollover

Tags: javascript, html

I have the page here at [www.thetotempole.ca/javas2.html/](http://thetotempole.ca/javas2.html) and basically I have a table with images and when the user rolls over one of the images I want it to enlarge and then return to normal on roll-out. Is there anyway this can be done? Here is my javascript/HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <script>
         var today = new Date();
         var daynames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
         var monthnames = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
         var prodnames = new Array("Apple","Dell","IBM","Toshiba","Atari");
         var imgArray = new Array();

            imgArray[0] = new Image();
            imgArray[0].src = 'images/apple.jpg';

            imgArray[1] = new Image();
            imgArray[1].src = 'images/dell.jpg';

            imgArray[2] = new Image();
            imgArray[2].src = 'images/ibm.jpg';

            imgArray[3] = new Image();
            imgArray[3].src = 'images/toshiba.jpg';

            imgArray[4] = new Image();
            imgArray[4].src = 'images/atari.jpg';

            imgArray[5] = new Image();
            imgArray[5].src = 'images/commodore.jpg';

         prodnames.push("Commodore");

         var proddescs = new Array();
         proddescs[0] = "It might be fruit, or it might be an iPhone";
         proddescs[1] = "Buy this one online at dell.com";
         proddescs[2] = "If you want a mainframe they still have some";
         proddescs[3] = "Get a discount through SAIT (maybe)";
         proddescs[4] = "Try a classic gaming machine";
         proddescs[5] = "64k should be enough for anyone";
         //alert(proddescs);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Images</th>
         </tr>
         <script>
            for (var i=0; i<prodnames.length; i++)
            {
               document.write("<tr>");
               document.write("<td>" + prodnames[i] + "</td>");
               document.write("<td>" + proddescs[i] + "</td>");
               document.write("<td>" + imgArray[i] + "</td>");
               document.write("</tr>");
            }
         </script>
      </table>
      <p>
         <script>
            //Tuesday Nov. 5, 2013
            var dayofweek = daynames[today.getDay()];
            //alert(dayofweek);
            var month = monthnames[today.getMonth()];
            var dateofmonth = today.getDate();
            var year = today.getFullYear();
            alert(dayofweek + " " + month + ". " + dateofmonth + ", " + year);
            document.write(dayofweek + " " + month + ". " + dateofmonth + ", " + year);
         </script>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Also, my images do not seem to be appearing in the table either. Please help!

Comment: I would recommend you not to split up your JavaScript and not to place it at different locations in your html document. Imagine a JavaScript-heavy project where your approach would result in messy and hard-to-maintain source code. Instead, [put your JS at the bottom of your page](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, it's possible to do that pretty easily using CSS:

```
table td:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

I have a working example on jsBin (after some cleanup): http://jsbin.com/iDiHErO/1/edit

Comment: I would also add the -moz-transform property for Gecko browsers after the webkit-specific property.

Comment: Normally I would do as well, but [firefox includes the unprefixed version already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility), so there's no need for it ;) Thanks for the reminder anyway